# Should I use FFMPEG library vs CLI

Tags: java, spring-boot, ffmpeg

In terms of performance, what is better to use, an FFMPEG library(like https://github.com/kokorin/Jaffree) or the FFMPEG command line interface?

Comment: Another consideration may involve licensing. ffmpeg command is GPL, and as long as you use it as such, your solution may be closed source. The ffmpeg libraries are LGPL, which means that you must be very careful linking to them, or face the consequences.

Comment: That is reversed. LGPL allows linking with closed source components. GPL doesn't. In any case, ffmpeg CLI can be LGPL or GPL or non-free.

Answer (score 3):

My initial thought was: this is an "opinionated" question, thus off topic. But then, I think there is a clear technical answer for this

Basically you want to **programmatically** use FFMPEG to solve some problem for you, from **within** your Java application. Therefore the answer is pretty much straight forward: when you want to things programmatically, then use that interface, that is intended for programmatic usage.

Meaning: you definitely prefer the API over using "raw" system command calls to invoke the client manually.

Why:

- A library/API gives you **compile time** safety. You have method calls with types, and whatnot
- The CLI ... only allows you to pull together a string "manually", and to fire that. If it works: great, but if not ... you only find out at runtime.

Beyond that: if you are talking about a "serious" project, then sooner or later, your code might want to do **different** things. And then the points from above just "multiply". Instead of one single command line string you can prepare for, you know build that string dynamically.

Long story short: for a simple problem, maybe the CLI is a good solution. But then: why wrap that in java, then you could as well write a small shell or python script as a small wrapper around the call you need.

Comment: Another concern I have is that Java wrappers go outdated sooner or later. For example Xuggler was a good library but now is deprecated. It's difficult to decide a wrapper to stick with long term.

Comment: @Lauren I agree. But note: in the end, the question is: do you really on some 3rd party API, or do you **create your own API**. Because that is the end result when you use the CLI, but "build around" that CLI in java code.

Comment: In my case it's going to be less than 10 operations on given videos

Comment: @Lauren Then I would rather write a python script ;-)